# Exception when attempting to connect to SQL Server CE from C#

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I'm an newbie who is trying to get learn some web programming. I'm making my site in VS 2012 using C#. I've got a database connected in the App_Data folder, using SQL Server CE 4.0. I'm attempting to connect to it as follows:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd1 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Admin FROM SystemUsers WHERE Email=" + user.Email);
SqlCeDataReader admin = null;
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
conn.Open();
admin = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
```

When I execute this, I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll but was not handled in user code

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong? I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

Comment: You should be using `using` with those objects, such as `using(var cmd = new sqlCommand()) {  }`, so they dispose properly and the connection is closed (anything that implements IDisposable). Also, never use string concatenation for SQL statements; your code is vulnerable to SQL injection; you should use SQL parameters.

Comment: Try stepping through the code in the debugger and when the exception pops up, you should be able to drill into it to see the Message and possible InnerException.Message.  The message might be a bit vague, but it is a starting point.

Comment: At some point, you should catch the exception and display it somewhere via `ex.ToString()`

Comment: Once you get the exception error, we might be more help. Also, if you're a newbie, you might want to look into using MVC 4 if you're going to do web dev as it introduces you to some more up-to-date principles especially having to do with databasing, etc.

Comment: You said that your database is in the APP_Data directory, but your connection string assumes that is in the root directory of your site

Comment: Ryan - Thanks, I will look into that. I'm using MVC 4 for the website login from a tutorial I followed.

I'll drill in and grab the exception error. Thanks for the security tip Brad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that your database is in the APP_Data directory, but your connection string assumes that is in the root directory of your site.

Try with

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source|DataDirectory|\MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

The |DataDirectory| is a placeholder string that the NET Framework changes to a predefined location where you data files are [supposed to stay](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/)

And this is how I would change your code

```
using(SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source|DataDirectory|\MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"))
using(SqlCeCommand cmd1 = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Admin FROM SystemUsers WHERE Email=@mail", conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", user.Email);
    SqlCeDataReader admin = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    while(admin.Read())
    {
      .....
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have made this changes:

- Added a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) around the creation of the connection and of
  the command. This will ensure proper closing and disposing of the two
  objects.
- Added a [parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) to avoid problems in parsing text strings
  and [Sql Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Steve. Unfortunately its still spitting out the same error. I did extract the exception, it is the filepath.

""The path is not valid. Check the directory for the database. [ Path = ~\\APP_DATA\\MainDb.sdf ]"}"

Comment: MainDb.sdf is the database name, i changed your connection string suggestion accordingly.

Comment: You could also try with the substitution string `"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MainDb.sdf;......"`

Comment: That got rid of the initial error, thanks! Now its saying "{"ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized."}" I'm doing something else wrong as well I suppose.

Comment: I think your connection string should be `@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MyData.sdf;...`.